# Netty 4.0.0.Alpha2-SNAPSHOT maven availability

Tags: netty

Is there a maven repository for the latest 4.0.0.Alpha2-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score -1):

Yeah there is..

http://repository-netty.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/